# Jenkins-IntelliJ Idea Integration

Tags: jenkins, jenkins-plugins, build.gradle, jenkins-job-dsl, jenkins-groovy

I am trying make auto-completion work with IntelliJ Idea to test my groovy script with specific version of set of jenkins plugins similar to intellisense in visual studio. I took the following Github project to start to understand how it works.
https://github.com/sheehan/job-dsl-gradle-example

video: https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=SSK_JaBacE0

My gradle build was successful as it it has pulled all the dependencies required to get it work like visual studio intellisense.
But somehow the DSL APIS(https://jenkinsci.github.io/job-dsl-plugin/) are not recognized.

```
>>    folder(basePath) {
    description 'This example shows how to create a set of jobs for each github branch, each in its own folder.'
}
```

The idea.gdsl file  supposed to make it work.

Content of idea.gdsl:

```
>>   def ctx = context(pathRegexp: /.*\/jobs\/.*groovy/)
     contributor(ctx, {
       delegatesTo(findClass('javaposse.jobdsl.dsl.DslFactory'))
     })
```

i am getting error "delegatesto can not be applied com.intellij.psi.psiclass"
I am not able to understand what to do next.

I am new Gradle and Intellij. Anyone used the github project and made it work? Any other solution?